# Remember not recompose when value change in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am increasing a value and I want to change color of text on that bases. When my value change  my text color is not changing.

**PairStateFul**

```
@Composable
fun PairStateFul() {
    var selectedIndexOfAvailableItem by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }
    val pairButtonColor = remember {
        if (selectedIndexOfAvailableItem != -1) {
            Color.Blue
        } else {
            Color.Yellow
        }
    }
    Column {
        PairStateLess(
           pairButtonColor,
            selectedIndexOfAvailableItem,
            onSelectedIndexOfAvailableItem = { selectedIndexOfAvailableItem += it }
        )
    }

}
```

**PairStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun PairStateLess(pairButtonColor: Color,
    selectedIndexOfAvailableItem: Int,
    onSelectedIndexOfAvailableItem: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
        Text(
            "Hello World!",
            color = pairButtonColor
        )
    Button(onClick = {
        onSelectedIndexOfAvailableItem(selectedIndexOfAvailableItem)
    }) {
        Text(text = "item $selectedIndexOfAvailableItem")
    }
}
```

**PairStateFulPreview**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PairStateFulPreview() {
    PairStateFul()
}
```

I know my increase counter logic is wrong. I don't want to solve logic. My main problem is when `selectedIndexOfAvailableItem` change then my `pairButtonColor` will also change.

Comment: Why is your `pairButtonColor` using `remember` at all? It isn't necessary.

Comment: So **remeber** is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you don't need a `remember` at all - Compose is already never going to change anything that `pairButtonColor` relies on unless `selectedIndexOfAvailableItem` changes, so can simply remove the `remember` and write:

```
val pairButtonColor =  if (selectedIndexOfAvailableItem != -1) {
    Color.Blue
} else {
    Color.Yellow
}
```

But to understand why your `remember` isn't working, it is important to understand what `remember { }` is doing. When you write

```
val pairButtonColor = remember {
  // ...
}
```

The code in the block is only run once and the value it returns is remembered (that's the whole point of `remember`).

This is why `remember` also has a version that take [a single key](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function0)) or [multiple keys](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)):

> Remember the value returned by `calculation` [your code block] if all values of `keys` are equal to the previous composition, otherwise produce and remember a new value by calling `calculation`.

Which would mean if you want your `remember` to rerun when `selectedIndexOfAvailableItem` changes, then it would need to be one of the keys you use:

```
val pairButtonColor = remember(selectedIndexOfAvailableItem) {
    if (selectedIndexOfAvailableItem != -1) {
        Color.Blue
    } else {
        Color.Yellow
    }
}
```

But as per the [Best practices around using remember](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices), usages of `remember` like this, where the source of the data is already a remembered value, are mostly around avoiding expensive calculations (i.e., if the block of code was very expensive to rerun, a `remember` on `pairButtonColor` might be helpful) or calculations that rely on remembered values that are changing rapidly (where `remember` + `derivedStateOf` would help improve performance).

In your case, neither apply - an `if` check is something that doesn't require `remember` at all.

Comment: I really appreciate it.  It works without `remember` function. I'll keep in mind to use of this.