# Managing nested state for checkboxes with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-list

I am facing a weird issue with jetpack compose where I can get a child state to manage itself, or have the parent state manage child state, but not both.

In the below example (I removed a lot of positioning/modifier fluff), you'll see that I have a `Switch()` component that is used to toggle the state of the individual `CustomCheckbox` components below. In my current implementation (below screenshot), I am able to check and uncheck the individual boxes just fine, but the toggle is not refreshing the state of each nested checkbox.

[image: Example]

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyView(state: MyState) {
    val checkboxes = remember { state.checkboxes.toMutableStateList() }
    val (toggleState, updateToggleState) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column() {
        Row() {
            Switch(
                checked = toggleState,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    val newCheckboxesState = checkboxes.map { checkbox -> checkbox.copy(checked = it) }
                    checkboxes.clear()
                    checkboxes.addAll(newCheckboxesState)
                    updateToggleState(it)
                }
            )
            Text(text = "Check all boxes")
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(5.dp))

        Card() {
            Column() {
                Text(text = "Check individual boxes:")
                LazyColumn() {
                    items(checkboxes) {
                        CustomCheckbox(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}


@Composable
fun CustomCheckbox(
    state: MyOtherState,
) {
    val (checked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(state.checked) }

    Card() {
        Column() {
            Row() {
                Checkbox(
                    checked = checked,
                    onCheckedChange = { setChecked(it) },
                )
                Text(text = state.description)
        }
    }
}
```

I set up a test where I just removed the `checkboxes.clear()` call to see if new checkboxes would render with the correct state, and that behaved exactly as expected. I've also found that `checkboxes.clear()` on its own works fine. What *doesn't* seem to work is use of those two things in conjunction. The best way I can describe it: `CustomCheckbox` is "remembering" its old state on recomposition.

I've spent a full day on this and can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would keep the state of the 3 checkboxes in a ViewModel, would make things a lot simpler.

Comment: If I understood correctly, checkboxes = newCheckboxesState would be working. If yes, because recomposition would be triggered on assignment operation, not when same object reference is updated. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @prateek With a mutable state list, recomposition occurs when the list is updated. I confirmed this through my final test (last paragraph of original post).

Comment: @TomBerghuis - Without going into much detail, that is not an option in my case. I need these to work as independent composeables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was really simple. Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74565765/9576194) on another post for containing the information I needed.

The solution was to update `CustomCheckbox`:

```kotlin
// Instead of:
val (checked, setChecked) = remember { mutableStateOf(state.checked) }

// Do this:
val (checked, setChecked) = remember(state.checked) { mutableStateOf(state.checked) }
```

This is because `remember` has a few variations that accepts keys, and these keys are used to by `remember` to identify if something needs to be recomposed.